# Can anyone ID this plant?

Tags: identification

We've had this small shrub in our garden for at least 7 years, so it's definitely a perennial. It has a lovely fragrance that I can only describe as 'bubblegum' and it has lovely purple flowers in the Spring. [image]Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Where is the plant growing?  What part of the world?

Comment: Square stems? Looks vaguely mint like. There are *lots* of variants.

Comment: Possibly Agastache?

Comment: I agree with @DCookie ... Agastache genus, possibly Agastache cana.